# WPF convert 2d mouse click into 3d space

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have several geometry meshes in my Viewport3D, these have bounds of (w:1800, h:500, d:25).

When a user clicks in the middle of the mesh, I want the Point3D of (900, 500, 25)...

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` with the callback.

- If you have a `Viewport3D` containing the model, you can just pass in a `PointHitTestParameters` containing the mouse location.
- If you need to operate directly on a `Visual3D`, pass in a `RayHitTestParameters` computed from your camera parameters and the mouse location.

In either case your callback will be called with a `RayTestHitResult`, and if you hit a mesh it will be a `RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult`.  This includes a `Point3D` property telling you the 3D point in space that was hit, and also the mesh and triangle that was hit.

See [3D Hit testing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf3d/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing/) for more details.