# How get mouse 3d position in 3dviewport in wpf?

Tags: wpf

How give mouse position when user click on 3d shape in 3dviewport.
I want X,Y and Z .
thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF convert 2d mouse click into 3d space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727268/wpf-convert-2d-mouse-click-into-3d-space)